# Twitter SDK using in iphone application

Tags: twitter, ios5

I am new in iphone application world.I have some question
1.How can i use twitter SDK in my app?
2.What is the procedure to use twitter in iphone app??

I am using iPhone SDK 5.0
Is it any running demo code available for simple twitter SDK or API used??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a Twitter Framework you can use as of iOS 5.0's SDK. Careful though. Some of the methods have been deprecated in 6.0.